# p tags text overlay on responsive bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with bootstrap when I want to apply responsive the first box will overly when I hit breakpoint 970px I don't know why it doing that I apply the 3 horizontal box   like this template but the p tag text on the first box will overlay with text on the second box 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="intrest"> 
    <h1>My Intrest</h1>
    <p>List of technolies that I used or intrested in</p>
    <div class="row-fluid">    
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Technoloty I used</h2> 
          <p>asp.net,Javascript,HTML/CSS,SQLserver,iOS,Visual Studio,C#,Objective-C,GIT,Windows,OSX</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>I intresed to use</h2> 
          <p>LAMP,MySQL,Laravel,PhoneGap,Drupal</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Hope or I study</h2> 
          <p>C/C++,Java,Andriod,Game Developmnt</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have no spaces for your text to wrap.**

Change:

```
<p>asp.net,Javascript,HTML/CSS,SQLserver,iOS,Visual Studio,C#,Objective-C,GIT,Windows,OSX</p>
```

to:

```
<p>asp.net, Javascript, HTML/CSS, SQLserver, iOS, Visual Studio, C#, Objective-C, GIT, Windows, OSX</p>
```

I'd recommend that you could also add.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

But then you'll be breaking lines mid-word which I don't think you'd want.